# How to push a docker image to Google Cloud Registry using GitLab ci pipeline

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, gitlab

I am trying to push a Docker image to Google Cloud Registry via the GitLab ci pipeline.

The image builds but when its time to push to registry i get the following error.

> denied: Token exchange failed for project 'nice-column-247216'. Caller
>   does not have permission 'storage.buckets.get'. To configure
>   permissions, follow instructions at:
>   https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/access-control

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
stages:
  - security
  - quality
  - test
  - build
  - deploy

image: node:10.16.0

services:
  - mongo
  - docker:dind

.before_script_template: &before_docker_script
  before_script:
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get -y install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg2 software-properties-common
    - curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | apt-key add -
    - add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get -y install docker-ce
    - curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.23.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
    - chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
    - echo "$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY" > key.json
    - docker login -u _json_key --password-stdin https://eu.gcr.io < key.json

build:
  stage: build
  <<: *before_docker_script
  variables:
    DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG: 'eu.gcr.io/nice-column-247216/my-application'
  script:
    - docker build --cache-from "${DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG}" -t "${DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG}" .
    - docker push ${DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG}
```

As you can see I am logging in to Docker via the `json` key. You can see in the below image the permissions this token has, both Storage Admin and Storage Object Viewer.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that the docker login work ? Did you try with a corrupted key ?